# Program compiling program fail at links for objective c files

Tags: objective-c, ubuntu

I am trying to compile a program using its source code and I am unable too and the problem seems to happen in the same folder in every ocurrance, and when I check the files, they are all objective c language, could it be that I am missing libraries or programs? If so which may they be? I tried researching online and here but all I find is stuff on gcc and g++ but I already have both installed along with the boost library which is another pre-req for this program. Here are some of the command line outputs I got:

```
        "g++"    -o "phrase-extract/pcfg-score/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi/pcfg-score" -Wl,--start-group "phrase-extract/pcfg-score/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi/pcfg_score.o" "phrase-extract/pcfg-score/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi/main.o" "phrase-extract/pcfg-score/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi/tree_scorer.o" "phrase-extract/pcfg-common/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi/libpcfg_common.a"  -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_program_options-mt -lboost_system-mt -lboost_thread-mt -Wl,-Bdynamic -lSegFault -lrt -Wl,--end-group -g -pthread 


...failed gcc.link phrase-extract/pcfg-score/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi/pcfg-score...
...skipped <p/home/rowe/Moses/bin>moses_chart for lack of <pmoses-chart-cmd/src/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi>moses_chart...
...skipped <p/home/rowe/Moses/bin>moses for lack of <pmoses-cmd/src/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi>moses...
...skipped <p/home/rowe/Moses/bin>lmbrgrid for lack of <pmoses-cmd/src/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi>lmbrgrid...
...skipped <p/home/rowe/Moses/bin>CreateOnDiskPt for lack of <pOnDiskPt/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi>CreateOnDiskPt...
...skipped <p/home/rowe/Moses/bin>queryOnDiskPt for lack of <pOnDiskPt/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi>queryOnDiskPt...
...skipped <p/home/rowe/Moses/bin>pro for lack of <pmert/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi>pro...
...skipped <p/home/rowe/Moses/bin>kbmira for lack of <pmert/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi>kbmira...
common.copy /home/rowe/Moses/bin/processPhraseTable
...skipped <p/home/rowe/Moses/bin>processLexicalTable for lack of <pmisc/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi>processLexicalTable...
common.copy /home/rowe/Moses/bin/queryPhraseTable
...skipped <p/home/rowe/Moses/bin>queryLexicalTable for lack of <pmisc/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi>queryLexicalTable...
...skipped <p/home/rowe/Moses/bin>extract-ghkm for lack of <pphrase-extract/extract-ghkm/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi>extract-ghkm...
...skipped <p/home/rowe/Moses/bin>pcfg-extract for lack of <pphrase-extract/pcfg-extract/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi>pcfg-extract...
...skipped <p/home/rowe/Moses/bin>pcfg-score for lack of <pphrase-extract/pcfg-score/bin/gcc-4.6/release/debug-symbols-on/link-static/threading-multi>pcfg-score...
common.copy /home/rowe/Moses/lib/libLM.a
...failed updating 12 targets...
...skipped 12 targets...
...updated 8 targets...
```

Comment: I believe this is an implementation issue, which would be better answered over at StackOverflow. [Check out the FAQ to see what questions should be asked here.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq)